# Uncaught ReferenceError: search_for_all is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:49)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm basically calling a function called **search_for_all()** located in a JS file, on an **onclick** event of the button in my HTML page. But I keep getting the above error.

I'm supposed to print the result of the function in a `<p>` tag in my HTML file. Following is the code that has the **onclick** event-

`<a id="files" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="search_for_all('https://demo.dataverse.org', 0, 'file')">Files</a>`

I'm using `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;` inside my JavaScript function to print its result.

Answer (score 0):

Using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

If you attach the listener in the same scope that you define the function, it should work properly. For example:

HTML:

```
<a id="files" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Files</a>
```

Javascript:

```
// ... lines of code ...
// declaration of search_for_all function:
function search_for_all(url, param1, param2) {
  // ...
}
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('click', () => {
  search_for_all('https://demo.dataverse.org', 0, 'file');
});
```